# How to hide/disable "packages have been kept back" list

Tags: apt, upgrade

I'm on Ubuntu Server 14.04.2, and when I run `sudo apt-get upgrade` I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-generic-lts-utopic linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic
  linux-image-generic-lts-utopic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

As I understand it, on a production server it's probably not wise to run `apt-get dist-upgrade`, so I'd like to know if it's possible to hide "kept back" packages.

It's also strange that the kernel for Utopic is listed. Why would Ubuntu 14.04 want to upgrade to a kernel used in 14.10?